# Linear function definition

Tags: functions, definition

I'm trying to figure out what is linearity and what is a linear function. But the wikipedia page confused me.

Firstly it defines as polynomial :

> $f(x) = ax +c$

Than it defines as linear map:

> $f(x) + f(y) = f(x+y)$
>
> $     af(x) = f(ax)$

This two definitions do conflict with each other.

> $f(x) = 2x + 3\\
>  f(2) = 7\\
> f(1) + f(1) = 10 \neq 7$

Does linearity has different meanings at different contexts, or is there something I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse linear with affine functions. The rules you mention are only valid for linear functions, not for affine functions.

Comment: In calculus a linear function is any non-vertical line. In the rest of mathematics it is a map that satisfies the two conditions in the middle.

Comment: Yes, a linear function in the familiar $ax+b$ sense is not a linear mapping. Frustrating, but both terms are long-established and unlikely to change.

Comment: @MattL. I've seen linear and affine functions used interchangeably.  I disagree with such use, but it is done.

Comment: @GitGud You're right, I just wanted to point out that here it is exactly this difference that causes the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces (i.e., set whose elements you can *add* to and *subtract* from one another, and which you can *multiply* with elements from some field $K$ (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$,$\mathbb{Q}$,$\mathbb{C}$,$\ldots$) then $$
  f \,:\, A \to B 
$$
is called *linear* if $$\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x + y) &=& f(x) + f(y) &\text{for all $x,y \in A$,} \\
  f(\lambda x) &=& \lambda f(x) &\text{for all $x \in A$, $\lambda \in K$.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
Note that you don't really need $A$ and $B$ to be vector spaces here, though - the definition is sensible as long as there are operations $+ \,:\, A\times A \to A$ and $+ \,:\, B\times B \to B$, and (for the second part) also operations $\cdot \,:\, K\times A \to A$ and $\cdot \,:\, K\times B \to B$.

Note that the graph of a linear function $f \,:\, \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is necessarily a line *through the origin*. Thus, not *every* function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose graph is a line is linear - that's true *only* if the line goes through the origin. Functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ whose graph is a line, but *doesn't* necessarily go through the origin are called *affine*.

For polynomials, unfortunately, polynomials of degree $1$, i.e. of the form $ax + b$, are often called *linear*, even though they *aren't* linear functions, only *affine* functions.